# PHP Convert file path to DOS short 8.3 format

Tags: php, path, command

I am trying to compile a list of oracle forms and reports through command line. The command line is executed using **PHP EXEC** Method.

Example:

```
exec ("ifcmp60.exe c:\my forms\accounts config.fmb");
```

The problem is that the file path contains spaces and the external programs **return error invalid file path** On reading the documentation I came to know that the **file path must not contain spaces but if it does then the path must be provided in DOS 8.3 Format**

Is there any function in php language to convert a full path to filename into DOS Short path format? Or is there any algorithm to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use *escapeshellarg()* to filter the path you provide as second argument if it comes from outside.
In your case a simple quote should work:

```
exec ('"ifcmp60.exe" "c:\my forms\accounts config.fmb"');
```